# DocumentDB Partitioned Collection max 10GB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I originally had a non-partitioned collection with 400RU/s provisioned which had a max capacity of 10GBs. I used the Document DB migration tool to move this over to a partitioned collection but according to the the metrics explorer, the max capacity is still 10GB. Will the capacity automatically scale as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used the Document DB migration tool to move this over to a partitioned collection but according to the metrics explorer, the max capacity is still 10GB. Will the capacity automatically scale as needed?

As far as I know, it just enables us to adjust the **throughput level** after you created the collection. If you’d like to adjust the **default storage capacity** (the maximum storage size of the collection), you could create a support request on Azure portal. Besides, you could migrate data from your target collection to another partitioned collection with larger data storage (>10GB).

Comment: Like I said, I used the migration tool originally which created a new collection for me. There is no option to set the storage size of the collection that the tool will create so I am not sure how to migrate it.

Comment: Yes, DocumentDB data migration tool has no option to set the maximum storage size of the collection, you could [create a collection and set Storage Capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-create-collection) on Azure portal. Besides, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-import-data#a-iddocumentdbbulktargetaimport-to-documentdb-bulk-import) shows how to use the DocumentDB data migration tool to import data to Azure DocumentDB from various sources, please refer to it.